# Joomla installation on Azure creates site with no users

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation

I have just installed Joomla as a Web App on Azure by selecting it from the gallery. When I tried to log in to the back end I was told the user didn't exist, despite having given the username and password as part of the set-up process. To double-check I logged into the ClearDB MySQL database using MySQL Workbench and checked the `database.jos_users` table where I assumed (I'm a total Joomla newbie if you hadn't guessed) the user data would be. There are no rows in the table. Can I add an admin user by directly adding data into this table? If I can, what would the SQL for that be?

Or should I just delete the entire installation and try again making the admin username "admin" instead of trying to be clever and putting something non-obvious as the username as I did this time?

Answer (score 1):

You can enter Joomla user manually using phpMyAdmin enter username, email and password (password should be md5 encrypted) and also activation field must be set to 1.
Then you will need to map the user to user group in table #__user_group_map. For super administrator access group_id should be 8 which is super user group id.
That's it now you will be able to login with username and password you have just created.

Answer (score 0):

I went for trying again without changing the admin username and this time it worked. I now have an operational Joomla site.